# Google Sheets: Removing everything from a URL up to '.com', and keeping everything after the first '/'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been searching for a formula on Google Sheets that removes everything from a url, up to the first /. For example:

```
www.example.com/example/
www.example.com/example/example1
www.example.com/example/example1/example2
```

to:

```
/example/
/example/example1/
/example/example1/example2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

on column A is your input
paste this in column B `=IF(A2="",,RIGHT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".com\/.+"),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".com\/.+"))-4))`
you can drag it down without any problem

Hope it answered your question.

Comment: Not all site URLs end with .com domain right?

Answer (score 0):

Say your URL is in `A1`. Then

```
=regexreplace(A1,"[\w.-]*\.com/","")
```

works as long as the site portion of your URLs always end with .com.

When that is not true, it's a bit more cumbersome:

```
=substitute(A20,regexextract(A20,"[\w-.]*/"),"")
```

Quickly on why they work: `[\w.-]` means any character from A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, ., -. `*` means any number of the preceding. [`regexreplace()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) replaces **all** matching patterns. And that's why without specifically .com, `regexreplace()` doesn't work for your problem. [`regexextract()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) extracts the part of URL that you don't want. So we can use [`substitute()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215) to get rid of it.

---

If you are new to regular expression, I think this example is simple enough to get a little bit into it. For more complex scenarios, the use of regular expression will save us tons of work.

In your current problem, since you only need to recognize the first occurrence of / without more complex patterns, we can just search for that with [`find()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en) and thus

```
=right(A1,len(A1)-find("/",A1))
```

also works.

Comment: Hey Argyll! I appreciate your response! Thank you for also breaking down how it works! I also may have made a mistake and forgot to add that the URLs contain the 'https://' at the front as well. How would I go about changing what you gave me to work for this?

Comment: @ffirgn: Use `substitute()` and `iferror()` to remove it first. Think of it as "pre-processing".